# SSRS 2008 - inclusion of subreport causes main report to return no data

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, subreport

I have a report which worked perfectly.

I inserted a subreport at the top (basically a cover sheet)

Now the rest of the report runs, but has "no data available" all over it

What is going on?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They haven't processed the latest month end....d'oh

Why is there no option to "close issue due to question no longer being relevant"?